# jqueryui selectable: how use the same function for many behaviors?

Tags: jquery

How use the same function for many behaviors?

I have tried use trigger, but it dont work here. Have any ideas?

```
$( "#myId" ).selectable({
    selected: function(event, ui) {
       /* here is usefull code of the fuction */
        ...
    },

    unselected: function(event, ui) {
        /* HERE I WANT USE FUNCTION FROM 'selected' 
          (now i just copy all code here from 'selected') */
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try this:

```
var selectableHandler = function(event, ui){
    /* here is usefull code of the fuction */
};    
$( "#myId" ).selectable({
    selected: selectableHandler,
    unselected: selectableHandler
});
```

Comment: Yeah, i have thought about.. but may be exist another options? Tank you for this option of course.